# Is it possible to have a new title tag for each accordion heading?

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

My site hosts a large quantity of information with categories/subcats/sub-subcats (tabs) and then info divided into questions and answers in accordion format.

I would like to have a different title tag and/or URL for each level

E.g. Animals/reptiles/snakes/how-do-you-catch-a-snake (how do you catch a snake is an accordion heading).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple `<title>` tags are not allowed, but you could modify the `document.title` property using javascript. For example, this would work:

```
$('#animals, #reptiles, #snakes, #how-do-you-catch-a-snake').click(function(e) {
    //assuming selected tabs get a .selected class
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        //Assuming you want to make the `<title>` the same as the tab's contents
        document.title = this.innerHTML;
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

That makes a whole bunch of assumptions, but without code provided, I can't really give you a more fitting code. This should give you a general idea about how this could work though.

Comment: If this answer helped you get the result you wanted, please mark it as accepted via the checkmark to the left of this answer. That makes it clearer to others that your question has been answered.